# How to access treeview content from different module?

Tags: python, treeview, gtk

I got two classes in different modules, each is a gtk.TreeView/gtk.ListStore. After double click on row in first tree view (a catalogs list) the program should display some content in another tree view (also a catalogs list) depending on which row was double-clicked.

file_1.py

```
class A():
  def _init_(self):
    ...
    #this content (catalogs_1_list) is fixed to display
    #not using self.catalogs_1, etc.
    catalogs_1.set_model(catalogs_1_list)
```

file_2.py

```
class B(don't want inheriting A):
  def _init_(self):
    ...
    #this content (catalogs_2_list) should be changing depending on double-clicked row in tree view from class A
    #not using self.catalogs_2, etc.
    catalogs_2.set_model(catalogs_2_list)
```

file_3.py

```
class start_app():
  def _init_(self):
    containers(imported classes from modules)
```

How to access the row-position in first tree view (class A) from the second tree view (class B)? (I have tried different aproaches) I would apreciate hints for further searching, no fixed code is necessary. The code worked when it was in one class/one module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't access row-position in tree view from second class. Instead, you should connect to a signal, which indicates, that user selection has changed. There are 2 ways to do it. The code below is `C` but it's easy to convert it to python.

1. TreeView's "row-activated".

   ```
   void
   row_activated (GtkTreeView       *tree_view,
                  GtkTreePath       *path,
                  GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
                  gpointer           user_data)
   {
     GtkTreeIter iter;
     GtkTreeModel *model;
     gchar *id;

     model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (tree_view);

     if (!gtk_tree_model_get_iter (model, &iter, path))
      return;

     gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, ID_COL, &id, -1);
   }
   ```
2. TreeSelection's `"changed"`. You can obtain `GtkTreeSelection` from TreeView.

   ```
   static void
   changed (GtkTreeSelection *select,
            gpointer          udata)
   {
     GtkTreeIter iter;
     GtkTreeModel *model;
     gchar *id;

     if (!gtk_tree_selection_get_selected (select, &model, &iter))
       return;

     gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, ID_COL, &id, -1);
   }
   ```

`ID_COL` is something I use in my TreeView widget. But you also need a way to match items from both lists.